# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate a service in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Have spent way too much time trying to figure this out. Thanks for any help. .Net Core 3.1 trying to register a service in Startup.cs

> Error CS0311: The type 'Apex.UI.MVC.ProjectService' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)`. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Apex.UI.MVC.ProjectService' to 'Apex.EF.Data.IProjects'. (CS0311) (Apex.UI.MVC)

```
services.AddScoped<IProjects, ProjectService>();
```

```
using System;
using Apex.EF.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Linq;
using Apex.UI.MVC.Models.Projects;

namespace Apex.UI.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        private IProjects _projects;
        public ProjectController(IProjects projects)
        {
            _projects = projects;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var projectModels = _projects.GetAll();

            var listingResult = projectModels
            .Select(result => new ProjectIndexListingModel
            {
                Id = result.Id,
                ProjectName = result.ProjectName,
                ProjectImage = result.ProjectImage

            });

            var model = new ProjectIndexModel()
            {
                Project = listingResult
            };
            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Apex.EF.Data;
using Apex.EF.Data.Models;

namespace Apex.EF.Data
{
    public interface IProjects
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> GetAll();
        Project GetById(int id);
        void Add(Project newProject);
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Apex.EF.Data;
using Apex.EF.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApexServices
{
    public class ProjectService : IProjects
    {
        private ApexContext _context;
        public ProjectService(ApexContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(Project newProject)
        {
            _context.Add(newProject);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Projects
                   .Include(project => project.Status.IsInShop == true);
        }

        public Project GetById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Projects
                .Include(project => project.Status.IsInShop==true)
                .FirstOrDefault(project => project.Id == id);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it says `Apex.UI.MVC.ProjectService` do not implement `Apex.EF.Data.IProjects`. So is `Apex.UI.MVC.ProjectService` the correct  type registered?

Comment: Your `ProjectService` is declared outside the namespace.

Comment: Do you have another implementation of `ProjectService` in your code - specifically in the `Apex.UI.MVC` namespace? The one you have shown in your question would not be reported in an error as belonging to that namespace because it is in the global namespace. If you are using Visual Studio, right client on the `ProjectService` in the `AddScoped` line and click `Go To Implementation` - it will navigate to the class that is causing the error (HINT: It is not the same class you have shown in your question).

Comment: Ok, I edited post, there was some errant stuff I was testing left in there. 

ProjectService is implemented in a different project in solution "ApexServices". I have references to Data and have gone back and forth on references in different ways. It is like Startup can't see my Apex Services Tier.

Comment: @user1895831 The namespaces shown in the exception are different to the example code shown. There are probably conflicting types in the project (not shown). Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces shown in the exception are different to the example code shown. There are probably conflicting types in the project (not shown).

If that is really the case, then include the full namespace when registering the type with the container to avoid conflicts.

Based on the shown code, that would be

```
services.AddScoped<IProjects, ApexServices.ProjectService>();
```